# Preact X + Babel 7 + Webpack 4 + WDS don't work

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader, preact

I try to setup Webpack Dev Server but nothing works, it just doesn't put anything into `/dist`.

**Dir structure**:

```
├── dist
│   └── (empty)
├── package.json
├── public 
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── index.js 
│   └── style.css
├── webpack.config.js
└── yarn.lock
```

**This is my webpack config**:

```
const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname + '/public',
        inline: true,
        port: 80
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            babelrc: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
          {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          'react': 'preact/compat',
          'react-dom': 'preact/compat'
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I do something wrong with the dev server, but I tried everything, nothing works, even no errors in **console output**:

```
$ webpack-dev-server
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:80/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /assets
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /public
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: a4299a80758757ab09d6
Version: webpack 4.30.0
Time: 12583ms
Built at: 05/08/2019 4:49:40 PM
  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  4.48 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:80 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB
{main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js] 135 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js] 4.58 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js] 127 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react-monaco-editor/lib/index.js] 474 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:80] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:80 8.26 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170
bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.js] 268 bytes {main} [built]
    + 380 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

In browser I receive this message, and I know why: dist folder is empty!

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/assets/index.js”.
```

**My task is to just simply compile js and use it in html file hosted on WDS.**

Here are **.babelrc** and **package.json** if needed:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": [
                "last 2 versions"
              ]
            },
            "modules": false
            }],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

```
{
  "name": "sl-sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.16",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.0.0-beta.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This line `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/assets/index.js”.` makes its seem like its trying to access your js in the assets folder, which you don't have. Also it must be going somewhere, maybe a pathing issue if its not where expected.

Comment: @pmkro hm, I thought webpack will output compiled stuff to assets, isn't it? I don't understand how WDS works...

Comment: Your webpack config is specifying it's going into `dist`

Answer (score 1):

> I try to setup Webpack Dev Server but nothing works, it just doesn't put anything into /dist.

By default, WDS doesn't generate the build result in the output folder. it uses an in-memory-file-system which is faster.

> Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/assets/index.js”.

I don't see any configuration for creating the html file that will specify what js files should be loaded when your website is starting/loading.

You should use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin):

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'My App' })
```

Also, you can create your own index.html file that HtmlWebpackPlugin will use to create a copy from and edit that (instead of using the default index.html that this plugin provides):

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'My App',
      filename: 'path/to/index.html'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `.babelrc` file like so:
https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#setting-up-jsx

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "h",
      "pragmaFrag": "Fragment",
    }]
  ]
}
```

After several tries this worked for me.

I also changed `./src/index.js` file to `./src/index.jsx` - (with `import {h,render} from "preact";`), don't know if it makes a difference, though